# Use one conditional function with more than one execution path if condition is met

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have the following case statement,

```
 case WHEN
           DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL 6 MONTH),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) = DATE(NOW()) THEN
     CONCAT('You should by now have held a probationary review meeting.','You must get approval from the owners.') 
    END AS 'emailSentence'
```

The *emailSentence* will hold the concatenation of the two sentences. This *emailSentence* is referenced externally by another program.

I would like to use a different alias such as ***emailSentence2*** and refer to the second part of concat i.e. *'You must get approval from the owners.'* all within the same case statement. That would mean getting rid of *concat* which is fine. Is there a way of doing this ? If there is a way of doing this without using a case statement i would be happy to hear that too, but it needs to be conditional statment/function.

I do realise i can use a different case statement with the same condition but that would mean multiple case statments making the sql bloated.

Comment: is variable an option? select sentence as a variable, sentence2 to split the variable by first dot and take second part

Answer (score 1):

SQL has a very strict syntax. With `*` as the only exception, listing a column in a [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) will always look like

```
select ... , expression [[as] alias], ...
```

`case` will be part of `expression`, so it cannot span multiple columns, and cannot add/return multiple columns.

Anecdotal, SQL doesn't care too much about the code being short. For example, doing something like `select <expression> as value1, <expression> as value2, value1+value2 as value3` or `select <expression> as value ... where value=0` is not allowed, you would have to repeat those expressions.

Nevertheless, if you really don't want to repeat that expression, you could use a `left join` instead and have the comparison (once) as the `on`-condition:

```
select ..., e.emailSentence, e.emailSentence2 -- or just e.*
from ...
left join (
  select 
    'You should by now have held a probationary review meeting.' as emailSentence,
    'You must get approval from the owners.' AS emailSentence2
) e on DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL 6 MONTH),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) = DATE(NOW())
```

To clarify: if the `on`-condition is not true, the values will be `null`, just as in the `case`-version.

This solution will have it's own limitations, but might be an option for you.